# change date format in crystal report table field

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working on a  vb.net windows form application and also in crystal reports.

In my crystal report i am using one dataset, from this data set 
I am showing all my data. In this data set i have one filled the name, date(now this date field is showing date like Month-date-year(09-08-2011).

How i can format this date to (dd-MM-yyyy). I dont know how to format dataset fields
if any one please help me to find out[image]

I want to format the Date coming under details part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click the date field, and click Format, if formats of the date are not coming it means your data in database is not stored as a date but as an nvarchar or any other, if that is the case first you need to convert this field to date, and display here, and by right clicking it you can set the format of the date you like. let me know if you need help. thanks.